# How to show page content as well as post lists

Tags: blog-page

I am trying to make a blog page for my theme which is made with Bootstrap 3.x . My **page-blog.php** includes

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <div class="col-md-9">
    <?php 
        $list_of_posts = new WP_Query( array ('category_name' => 'blog'));
        if ( $list_of_posts->have_posts() ) : while ( $list_of_posts->have_posts() && $i < 10) : $list_of_posts->the_post(); ?>
        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    ?>
    </div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

With the above code, the blog page shows the list of my posts which are tagged as "blog". However, it does not show the content I have written for the page itself. Any ideas what codes I need to include to have that feature as well?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the answer. I should add the following just below `<div class="col-md-9">`

```
<div id="page-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<?php
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
            the_post_thumbnail('thumbs');
        endif;
        echo get_the_date('jS F Y');
        the_title();
        the_content();
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
</div>
```